# Solutions of the even exercises only with the tcolorbox package

Tags: tcolorbox

I produce exercises with `tcolorbox` for a textbook, and I want to let place for solution with the option `lowerbox=invisible`, for even exercises, and give the solutions of odd exercises in the end of the Textbook.. and, eventually, give all the solutions somewhere in the project of a book I'm writing about this course. I give an example, where I put the option `lowerbox=invisible` "locally", in the even exercises, to watch the reader the behavior I'm pursueing for the exercises, and I want to write the solutions only for even exercises, in the first time (inside the chapter), and in the second time, a file containing all the solutions, in the end of book.

I give examples of exercises, given in the doc of `tcolorbox`,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=section]{exercise}{+O{}}{%
enhanced,colframe=green!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,coltitle=green!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
label={exercise@\thetcbcounter},
attach title to upper=\quad,
after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
{\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution@\thetcbcounter}}},
lowerbox=ignored,
savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
record={\string\solution{\thetcbcounter}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
#1
}
\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
enhanced,colframe=red!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,coltitle=red!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise@#1} on page~\pageref{exercise@#1}:},
phantomlabel={solution@#1},
attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}
\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right) '
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[lowerbox=invisible]    %%  Local option
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(\sin(\sin x))^2
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( (\sin(\sin x))^2 \right) '
=2\sin(\sin x) \cos(\sin x) \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sqrt{x^3-6x^2+2x}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( \sqrt{x^3-6x^2+2x} \right) '
= \frac{3x^2-12x+2}{2\sqrt{x^3-6x^2+2x}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[lowerbox=invisible]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\cos((2x^2+3)^3)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( \cos((2x^2+3)^3) \right) '
=-\sin((2x^2+3)^3) 3(2x^2+3)^2 2\cdot 2x\\
&=-12x(2x^2+3)^2\sin((2x^2+3)^3).
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right) '
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\tcbstoprecording
\newpage
\section{Solutions}
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

and the pdf file obtained:

[image]
[image]

Comment: With other words, even numbered solutions shall not be shown immediately, but only later on?

Comment: yes.. and even exercises produced with the option `lowerbox=invisible`

Comment: Please restate your question ... your request is clamped together and it is hardly recognizable what you're really after...

Comment: I wrote "I want to let place for solution with the option `lowerbox=invisible`, for even exercises... so this option must be automated for all the even exercises. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to use a wrapper macro `\solutionbox` that decides to show the solution based on the swith `\ifshowallsolutions` or based on the number being odd or not.

The same is done for the `exercise` environment, preventing `lowerbox=ignored` and being `invisible` then.

Multiple labels warning are  prevented by using a different label name for the full bunch of solutions. Also, references to dropped solutions are caught by using `\IfRefUndefinedExpandable` from `refcount`.

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newif\ifshowallsolutions

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tcb@cnt@exercise}

\NewTColorBox[use counter=tcb@cnt@exercise,number within=section]{exerciseinternal}{s+O{}}{%
enhanced,colframe=green!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,coltitle=green!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
label={exercise@\thetcbcounter},
attach title to upper=\quad,
after upper={\IfRefUndefinedExpandable{solution@\thetcbcounter}{}{\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
{\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution@\thetcbcounter}}}},
IfBooleanTF={#1}{lowerbox=invisible}{lowerbox=ignored},
savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
record={\string\solutionbox{\thetcbcounter}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}{\number\c@tcb@cnt@exercise}},
#2
}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{+O{}}{%
  \ifodd\c@tcb@cnt@exercise%
  \exerciseinternal[#1]%
  \else
  \exerciseinternal*[#1]%
  \fi
}{\endexerciseinternal}

\NewDocumentCommand{\solutionbox}{+m+m+m}{%
  \ifshowallsolutions
  \solution{#1}{#2}
  \else
  \ifodd#3%
  \solution{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
  \fi
}


\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
enhanced,colframe=red!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,coltitle=red!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise@#1} on page~\pageref{exercise@#1}:},
phantomlabel={\ifshowallsolutions solutionredisplayed@#1\else solution@#1\fi},
attach title to upper=\par,
}{%
  \input{#2}%
}
\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}[coltitle=blue]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right) '
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}    %%  Local option
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(\sin(\sin x))^2
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( (\sin(\sin x))^2 \right) '
=2\sin(\sin x) \cos(\sin x) \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sqrt{x^3-6x^2+2x}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( \sqrt{x^3-6x^2+2x} \right) '
= \frac{3x^2-12x+2}{2\sqrt{x^3-6x^2+2x}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[lowerbox=invisible]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\cos((2x^2+3)^3)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( \cos((2x^2+3)^3) \right) '
=-\sin((2x^2+3)^3) 3(2x^2+3)^2 2\cdot 2x\\
&=-12x(2x^2+3)^2\sin((2x^2+3)^3).
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f ' (x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right) '
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\tcbstoprecording
\newpage
\section{Selected Solutions}
\tcbinputrecords

\section{All solutions}
\showallsolutionstrue
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very ingenious solution. Now, how can I insert the option `lowerbox=invisible`, for all the even exercises ?

Comment: I accepted your answer, even if it's incomplete for my purpose, and your ideas are wellcome for automating the option `lowerbox=invisible` ..

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: I've an idea for that...

Comment: Other thing. I don't understand very well your sentence "However, this will cause multiple labels."...

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Redisplaying the solutions would cause the same label name "solution@...` again -- but I have prevented this now. And I've made a wrapper also for the exercise environment box, now checking whether the exercise number is even or odd...

Comment: The solution is now as I wanted. Thak you

Comment: I looked again to the details of the solution.. the doc of the `refcount` package, the macros used, `IfBooleanTF`, `IfRefUndefinedExpandable`..etc .. The method you introduced is really ingenious and very useful for me. Many thanks another time

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: You're welcome. Happy TeXing